# Norton Internet Security is disabled, cannot access Internet

Tags: windows-vista, internet, norton-internet-security

On a client's computer running Vista x86, he installed Norton Internet Security 2011, and the Internet stopped working. I took a look, and Internet Explorer and a fresh copy of Firefox are not connecting. I can ping addresses (such as www.google.com and msn.com), and I get the same replies back on that computer as a second computer on the same network. I uninstalled Norton, and both browsers started working. I tried a fresh download from the [Norton website](http://us.norton.com/support/kb/web_view.jsp?wv_type=public_web&docurl=20080514162318EN&ln=en_US), installed it successfully, but still blocks the Internet.

The copy has NOT been activated yet, but I have a valid key with his receipt when he purchased it from Symantec. It has not asked for a key, but it's passed its period of working where it now wants it activated. Of course, with no Internet, it doesn't activate

Comment: Well, it's protecting him from the internet, right? What's the problem? :-)

Comment: Not the point :P It doesn't get online, and Norton is blocking the settings page until it can activate ONLINE

Comment: Well, my first choice would be to dump Norton. Second would be to contact Symantec. I'm sure they've dealt with this before.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now... And I'm teaching the tech how to do his job...

Comment: I should probably mention that it's not my computer, it's a customer's laptop. He has the email with the product key as well, so he obviously wants it installed

Comment: The tech fixed it with the NETSH winsock reset trick

Comment: Could you write up an answer and select it? It makes it more useful for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to an elevated Command Prompt and type

```
netsh winsock reset
```